# Xcode 7.3.1 : Unable to validate your application

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to upload an application to store and getting this error **Unable to validate your application**
The path '/var/folders/ml/4s9tjk05443_gtbcft66hnyr0000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.KVe/Packages/Walmart Cupons.ipa' does not contain a file.**. For more information please refer to the screenshot attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but then I used Application Loader and it worked correctly. After validating your app Export your app by selecting option as Save for iOS App Store Deployment and then Just upload your apps ipa using Application Loader.
Download it from here:-
https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_3.1.dmg[enter link description here](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_3.1.dmg)

Video to how use Application Loader
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWCDks75hg8

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try to use Application Loader to upload your app to the App Store.

1. Archive your build.
2. Select the build and click export.
3. Select "Save for iOS App Store Development".
4. Once you successfully exported your build, go to Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Application Loader.
5. Login with your app developer account.
6. On the lower right corner click "choose".
7. Select the .ipa file that you just exported earlier.
8. Click next to upload your app.

Before I always use Xcode to upload my build for App Store, but a lot of problems occur. But when I use the App Loader. These problems seem to disappear.

Hope this helps. :)